# Include module plugin in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins

I wrote an Auth plugin to check if the user is logged in. No unlogged user should be able to visit anything in the app except the login page.

So I have this in the file `application/modules/user/plugins/Auth.php`:

```
class User_Plugin_Auth extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity() 
               || $this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'login') return;
        $request->setModuleName('user');
        $request->setControllerName('auth');
        $request->setActionName('login');
    }
}
```

Then I made this in the `application.ini`:

```
pluginPaths.User_Plugin = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/user/plugins/"
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "User_Plugin_Auth"
```

However, no matter how I move the `Auth.php` file and no matter the name, I always get `Fatal error: Class 'User_Plugin_Auth' not found`. Please help me, I have wasted more than one hour on this and it's frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is to do with the filename. I would try creating copies of the files in these locations

```
application/modules/user/plugins/User_Plugin_Auth.php

application/modules/user/plugins/User/Plugin/Auth.php
```

naturally you only need one of them, so delete the others once you have found the one that works.

If that doesn't help that the syntax I have in my config (Fam is just the codename of the project)

```
resources.frontController.plugins.layout = "Fam\Controller\Plugin\Layout"
resources.frontController.plugins.route = "Fam\Controller\Plugin\Route"
```

as pointed out in comments that is php 5.3 - this should work in older versions assuming include paths are configured

```
resources.frontController.plugins.layout = "Fam_Controller_Plugin_Layout"
resources.frontController.plugins.route = "Fam_Controller_Plugin_Route"
```

which maps to the files in my library, eg

```
APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Fam/Controller/Plugin/Layout.php"
```

For reference in this project my Zend files are in

```
APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Zend"
```

so adjusting the files to be in the relative place should do the trick

is your autoloader configured? I have
    autoloaderNamespaces.0 = "Fam"

you might need something like

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "User_"
resources.frontController.plugins.UserAuth = "User_Plugin_Auth"
```

Comment: Isn't this `\\` thing namespaces of Zend2 and PHP5.3?

Comment: I am using Zend 1.1x and php 5.3... if you are not using namespaces, replacing the \ with _ might do the trick, sorry I am a little hazy - I am lucky that work with dedicated servers so can indulge my love of keeping up with version numbers - I will edit

Comment: I tried what you wrote up there, none worked. Is it even possible to have any plugin outside of the `/library` folder?

Comment: still the same error? Do you have autoloader namespaces configured? see above

Comment: I have just made a Plugin in the `/library` folder, now it works and that's it. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: An example of Zend's way or the highway perhaps! I have found it much easier to adapt me to zend than the other way around ;)